# Who attacked General Mapache's men even before Pancho Villa's men received weapons from the Wild Bunch?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wild-bunch

In [*The Wild Bunch* (1969)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065214/), At 92:08 into the movie, General Mapache's men is shown attacked by some unknown men, even before Pancho Villa's men received weapons from the Wild Bunch. Here is the picture, General Mapache & his men are escaping on the train from the attack.

[image]

IMDB Synopsis shows Pancho Villa's men attacked General Mapache's men, 
but at 100:02 into the movie, Pancho Villa's men receive weapons 
from The Wild Bunch.

[image]

So who atacked General Mapache's men?

Comment: Didn't I answer this already?

Comment: >>but at 100:02 into the movie, Pancho Villa's men receive weapons from The Wild Bunch<< The "full-blooded Indians" were described by Angel as "my people" and as "OF my village, but not FROM it." They were probably not directly affiliated with Pancho Villa's forces. Rather, Angel strongly implies that they are unaffiliated irregulars struggling to defend themself against Gen. Mapache.

Answer (score 1):

It was Pancho's Villa's men as indicated by the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Wild-Bunch,-The.html).

> ```
>        THIRTY OR FORTY BIG HATTED REVOLUTIONARIES probe for the
>        weakness of Mapache's position at the railroad station.
>        Note: Mapache's soldiers show signs of having recently suf-
>        fered a beating and it..is obvious that they are retreating...
> ```

Pancho Villa's revolutionary army was supplied with arms already...the guns supplied by the Wild Bunch were in **addition** to their existing armaments.

> As commander of the División del Norte (Division of the North) in the Constitutionalist Army, he was a military-landowner (caudillo) of the northern Mexican state of Chihuahua. Given the area's size and mineral wealth, it provided him with **extensive resources.**
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancho_Villa)</sup>

Villa was the commander of an entire army division but revolting against his own government...they would have been well supplied already.